# In VS Code API, how can one get the Python environment path?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When implementing a Visual Studio extension to be used with Python files in the VSCode editor, how can one programmatically get the path of currently selected Python environment?

My guess is that it is done with `python.pythonPath`, but I can't seem to make it work. If I use that directly within an extension `js`, it crashes. I also tried:

```
let python = vscode.extensions.getExtension('python');
python.pythonPath
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python.pythonPath` is a *setting*, so you can do this with VSCode's generic settings API (instead of having to rely on the Python extension exposing an API specifically for this):

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("python").get("pythonPath")
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know I had to get the configuration and then get the variable, separately.